# Create private message for each signer

Tags: c#, docusignapi

According to the DocuSign [Documentation](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-add-messages), it is possible to send an envelope where each signer in the envelope receives a "Private Message".  I have reviewed the DocuSign REST API documentation and was unable to find any reference to a private message, or details on how to create one.

Could someone provide details on the REST API implementation of the "private message" feature?  Additionally an example the [DocuSign .Net SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/) would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the **emailNotification** property for each recipient. Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#core-recipient-parameters)

Here is a sample [createEnvelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) request.

> POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

```
{
  "status": "sent",
  "recipients": {
      "signers": [
          {
             "email": "janedoe@acme.com",
             "name": "jane doe",
             "recipientId": 1,
             "emailNotification": {
                "emailSubject": "Please sign the  document(s) (jane doe)",
                "emailBody": "Hello Jane Doe,\r\n\r\nYour have a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the document.  ",
                "supportedLanguage": "en"
              },
              "tabs": {"signHereTabs": [ { "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "80", "yPosition": "80"}]}
          },
          {
             "email": "johnsmith@acme.com",
             "name": "john smith",
             "recipientId": 2,
             "emailNotification": {
                "emailSubject": "Please sign the  document(s) (john smith)",
                "emailBody": "Hello john smith,\r\n\r\nYour have a new document to view and sign.  Please click on the View Documents link below, review the content, and sign the document.  ",
                "supportedLanguage": "en"
              },
              "tabs": {"signHereTabs": [ { "documentId": "1", "pageNumber": "1", "xPosition": "80", "yPosition": "180"}]}
          }
      ]
  },
  "documents": [
      {
          "documentId": "1", "name": "Contract", "fileExtension": "txt", "documentBase64": "RG9jIFRXTyBUV08gVFdP"
      }
  ]
}
```

---

## Using the C# SDK

Complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/736280cc43e91752eb64a0221db80896#file-createenvelopefromtemplate-cs-L181-L260)

```
    public void CreateEnvelopeSeparateEmailNotificationForRecipients()
    {
        string accountID = Init();

        byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\test.pdf");
        var envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition()
        {
            Status = "sent",
            Recipients = new Recipients()
            {
                Signers = new List<Signer>() 
                {
                    new Signer()
                    {
                        Email = "janedoe@acme.com",
                        Name = "jane doe",
                        RecipientId = "1",
                        RoutingOrder = "1",
                        EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification()
                        {
                            EmailSubject = "Please sign the  document(s) (jane doe)",
                            EmailBody = "This is email body for Jane Doe"
                        },
                        Tabs = new Tabs() { SignHereTabs =  new List<SignHere>(){ new SignHere() { DocumentId = "1", XPosition = "100",YPosition = "300", PageNumber = "1" } } }
                    },
                    new Signer()
                    {
                        Email = "johnsmith@acme.com",
                        Name = "JohnSmith",
                        RecipientId = "2",
                        RoutingOrder = "1",
                        EmailNotification = new RecipientEmailNotification()
                        {
                            EmailSubject = "Please sign the  document(s) (John Smith)",
                            EmailBody = "This is email body for John Smith"
                        },
                        Tabs = new Tabs() { SignHereTabs =  new List<SignHere>(){ new SignHere() { DocumentId = "1", XPosition = "200",YPosition = "300", PageNumber = "1" } } }
                    }
                }
            },
            Documents = new List<Document>()
            {
                new Document()
                {
                    DocumentBase64 = System.Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes),
                    Name = "Contract",
                    DocumentId = "1"
                }
            }               
        };

        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi();
        EnvelopeSummary envelopeSummary = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountID, envDef);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Yes I believe that this method, along with the recipient note attribute should give us the functionality we need.  We are using the c# SDK, I will need to review that and make sure that it is supported.

Comment: Updated the answer with the code to create the envelope using the C# sdk.